# Android ScrollView Icons

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an app using the scroll view but I have problem. The first button is not visible entirely when I scroll to the top here is my xml and image from the app.I have tried different different ways to fix it but was not possible ://(in the image you can see that the first button is not visible only some part  of is visible)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/background">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/angle" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/currency" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/area" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/datasize"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/datasize" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: as you can see there is a button in the top but only its lower part is visible]

Comment: increase height of scrollview

Comment: @Shahzeb I am gonna add more buttons I just wanted to set some limitation to the height in order to not merge the buttons with the background image ://

Comment: I see. Try to move ScrollView in a fixed height layout and then set the height and width of ScrollView to match parent.

Comment: totally unclear what your screenshot is s'possed to inform about your situation...

Comment: According to your xml `100 + 100 + 100 + 100 == 280`. You should find some other way and *not* use a scrollview, or at least make it bigger (height)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak but isnt that the main purpose of the scrollview, to be able to scroll through items in my case buttons

Comment: Yes, since this looks an awful lot like a menu where you would want all buttons visible at the same time, a scroolview looks like the wrong choice. Maybe a linear layout with weights? then all buttons would scale up/down and have the same height

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I have more buttons to add about 12 which wont fit in the screen

Comment: try removing `android:layout_gravity="center"` on your linearLayout to just cut off the last button, but I think you should strongly think about a different approach to the whole UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works for me:
removing `android:layout_gravity="center"` from `LinearLayout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/background">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/angle" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/currency" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/area" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/datasize"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/datasize" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```